# How do you extract phone numbers from email bodies in Outlook?

Tags: regex, csv, outlook

I have a pretty large account full of ~20k emails in Outlook and I need to extract phone numbers from those emails.

An example of an email would be:

```
From: Amy Schwartz <amy@blahdyblah.com>

Dear Anatoliy, 
I want you to do blahdy blahdy blah.

Amy Schwartz
(347) 555-1212 <---- I want this
Blahdy Blah Company
```

The idea is to go through every email and match the last Phone number via regex and export a list in the following format:

- Name: Name from the "From" field
- Email: Email from the "From" field
- Phone: The last phone number matched in the email text

Do you have any ideas on how to go about doing this?

UPDATE: Didn't find any prebuilt solutions, but I'm hacking together my own [using this](http://www.codetwo.com/freeware/outlook-export/). codeTwo Outlook Express. You can export any email field (body, HTML body, from, from name) to CSV. It's a little slow (3 seconds a message on my i7 iMac running a Win7 VM). But it works :) And from there I will probably just put in a database and do some regex magic. Will post process once I'm done.

Comment: i would suggest first get all the lines which contains numbers no matter what ever it is. i am assuming phone numbers can be very different form if you are dealing with 20K size. then play with a regex which picks any numbers which only contains - or ) . hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It's super easy if you know how to make a Node.js script (but I'm sure you can write one in Bash).

1) Use [Outlook Export](http://www.codetwo.com/freeware/outlook-export/) plugin to export all your emails to a CSV. Make sure email is first column, name is second column, and Body (text) is 3rd column.

2) Write the following script in Node JS in the same directory as you CSV of emails

```
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('csv');
csv()
    .from.stream(fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/data.csv'))
    .to.path(__dirname+'/out.csv')
    .transform( function(row){
      var match = row[2].match(/(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})/);
        return '"' + row[0] + '","' + row[1] + '","' + (match ? match[0] : '') + '"\n';
    })
    .on('error', function(error){
      console.log(error.message);
    });
```

and run it using `node script.js`.

And that's it! Runs super quickly (~20 secs for 20k emails).

Let me know if you have any suggestion (or package this into a downloadable executable)